# Is there a way to see how many times a song has been played?

Tags: deezer

I've uploaded my band's album some time ago and I would like if there's a way to see how many times a song has been played, and if possible the geolocation from where they have been played.
I've checked the API objects but I wasn't able to find anything to check this.

Many thanks in advanced.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the information you want is not accessible through the API.